# TFS rest api authorizing GET but not PATCH

Tags: c#, rest, tfs

I'm trying to change the status for a work item using the rest API provided by my TFS 2015 Update 3 (on premises).
When I try to get the list of my items, everything works fine:

```
var client = new RestClient(uri);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(this.TFSUsername, this.SecurityToken);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

After I get this answer and I have all the information I need, I was going to update the status of one of these work items.

Using the same approach (and of course, the same credential), I'm getting the 401 status code, **as I was trying to do it anonymously**.

The only difference is that I'm using the verb PATCH (as documentation said I have to) and that I'm passing a body to identify what status I want to edit.

This is the code I'm using for the edit:

```
var client = new RestClient(uri);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(this.TFSUsername, this.SecurityToken);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

string body = @"
  {
   'op':'add',
   'path':'/fields/System.State',
   'value':'Closed'
  }";
request.AddJsonBody(body);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Any hints on why just changing the HTTP VERB is causing me this authorization issue?

Trying to do it with Postman is causing me the same issue.

UPDATE:

looking at the response header, I noticed this:

```
X-TFS-ProcessId →e2b98235-1d3a-4bb7-868f-0d91805aa307
ActivityId →08909688-ac81-4c37-9cea-b47e84fd3efe
X-TFS-Session →08909688-ac81-4c37-9cea-b47e84fd3efe
X-VSS-E2EID →08909688-ac81-4c37-9cea-b47e84fd3efe
X-FRAME-OPTIONS →SAMEORIGIN
WWW-Authenticate →Basic realm="http://xxxxxxx/tfs"
WWW-Authenticate →Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate →NTLM
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
P3P →CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
Lfs-Authenticate →NTLM
X-Content-Type-Options →nosniff
Date →Thu, 28 Feb 2019 00:20:57 GMT
Content-Length →0
```

What caught my attention was:

**WWW-Authenticate →Basic realm="http://xxxxxxx/tfs"**

**WWW-Authenticate →Negotiate**

**WWW-Authenticate →NTLM**

So it would support Basic authentication as the Get, but is not working. Are "Negotiate" and "NTLM" interfere somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a personal access token to authenticate? If so double check that the token has read and write/update permissions.

Comment: thanks @JMarlow but that personal access token has already all the permission

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trying, I found out that the solution is pretty easy.

To make it work from the Authentication point of view, it's enough to use the **NtlmAuthenticator** (with Username and password) instead of the HttpBasicAuthenticator (even though is working for the get).
I replaced my authenticator with NtlmAuthenticator for both get and patch and now is working fine.

```
var client = new RestClient(uri);
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(this.TFSUsername, this.TFSPassword);
```

The other tricky part that I found out (not precisely linked to the authentication) is that for the PATCH the content type has to be **application/json-patch+json**

Hope it helps